# SQL: from predicate logic to SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, predicate

I am trying to understand how to effectively translate predicate logic to SQL Queries. I am stuck at:

```
For all P(x), (for all P(y), (Knows(x,y) -> Likes(x,y)))
```

which I further translated to:

```
-exists P(x), (exists P(y), (Knows(x,y) /\ -Likes(x,y)))
```

Using as 'formulas':

```
for all x, (A -> B) <=> -exists x, (A /\ -B); for all x, (A) <=> -exists x, (-A)
```

With the probability of starting wrong, here is the initial enunciation:

```
Write a query that returns the name of all persons that like everyone they know.
```

Where both Knows and Likes tables are NOT symmetric and simply contain foreign keys to Person table, and hence express Person X Knows/Likes Person Y.

How would the SQL SELECT query look like, for the above?

I have tried this but doesn't work:

```
SELECT P.name 
FROM Persons P 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Knows K 
    WHERE K.personB_id NOT IN (
        SELECT L.personB_id 
        FROM Likes L 
        WHERE K.personA_id = L.personA_id 
        AND K.personB_id <> L.personB_id))
```

Comment: Nice question. There are multiple solutions in SQL, and the most effective one is not necessarily a straightforward translation of the predicate logic. I wonder why you have not applied the more obvious rewrite `forall P(y) (~knows(x,y) \/ likes(x,y))` for a particular fixed `x`, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert A->B <=> -A \/ B is what I knew beforehand, as well. However, in my course, we were recommended to use those 'formulas' that I have written and so I tried doing it that way. In any case, how would the query look like for "forall P(y) (~knows(x,y) \/ likes(x,y))" ?

Comment: What I have (and doesn't work) is: SELECT P.name
FROM Persons P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Knows K WHERE K.personB_id NOT IN(SELECT L.personB_id FROM Likes L WHERE K.personA_id = L.personA_id AND K.personB_id <> L.personB_id))

Comment: I'd start by finding a list of people who know people they don't like. Then Select from Persons where they're not in that list. edit: I see you're on the right line, but instead of "not in" try left join looking for null because you're conditioning on 2 fields rather than a single field not being present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a list of people who know people that they don't also like. Then select from Persons where they are not in that set.

```
SELECT FROM Persons
    WHERE Persons.ID NOT IN (
        SELECT Knows.PersonA 
        FROM Knows LEFT JOIN Likes
        ON Knows.PersonA = Likes.PersonA
        AND Knows.PersonB = Likes.PersonB
        WHERE Likes.PersonB is null
   )
```

Comment: Works perfectly! The fact I haven't thought of using LEFT JOIN and a NULL check clearly implies I need more practice ^^